# How to write the proper regexp?

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regexp for these occurences:

works for:

```
*menupoint/example
```

and not accept this:

```
*menupoint/example/example
```

so after the menupoint teher will be maximum one /.
I tried this one but not working:

```
%menupoint\/[^\/]+
```

Thanks for the helps!

Comment: `[^\/]+` matches 1+ chars other than `/`. Maybe you need `.menupoint\/.+` (`.+` matches any 1+ chars)?

Comment: sorry its menupoint :)

Comment: There is a mismatch between your regex and your hypothetical input. Also, please format properly

Comment: Why does your regex start with `%`?

Comment: because before the menupoint can be anything

Comment: Then try `.menupoint\/.+` where `.` matches any char.

Comment: Does it help? Please add details to your question: what tool it is, how you are using the regex, what the method is...

Comment: not help because accept the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use "$" sign to match the end of the string, it will make sure the "/" after "menupoint" is the last "/" in your target string.

```
menupoint\/[^\/]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/WrALCc/1

Comment: start with .* and good

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `%` whith `.*`:

```
.*menupoint\/[^\/]+
```